# NCrunch can't build project that references Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk

Tags: azure-functions, ncrunch

I have an Azure Functions v3 (dotnet isolated) C# project that references `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk` version 1.0.4. When NCrunch tries to build this project it fails with the message: `..\..\..\..\..\..\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1150, 7): The target "NCrunchPrepareForBuild" does not exist in the project.` If I remove the package reference the build succeeds.

[Conditionally disabling](https://www.ncrunch.net/documentation/troubleshooting_ncrunch-specific-overrides) the reference with `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.0.4" OutputItemType="Analyzer" Condition="'$(NCrunch)' != '1'" />` doesn't work. Oddly, if I change that to `Condition="'$(NCrunch)' == '1'"` it does work, which suggests that the `$(NCrunch)` property has not been set at this point in the build process.

The line referenced by the error message looks like this:

```
<Target
      Name="PrepareForBuild"
      DependsOnTargets="$(PrepareForBuildDependsOn)">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by **arkiaconsulting** and **Clement**:

Paths triggered only for the NCrunch build

```
 <Target Name="CopyAzureFunctionOutput" AfterTargets="_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild" Condition="'$(NCrunch)' == '1'">
    <Exec Command="xcopy /y &quot;$(OutDir)\bin&quot; &quot;$(OutDir)&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

To disable the targets loading, you can set the `ExcludeRestorePackageImports` property to true in your project referencing the Azure Function package like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(NCrunch)' == '1'">
<ExcludeRestorePackageImports>true</ExcludeRestorePackageImports>
</PropertyGroup>
```

That way, the targets are not triggered, the files are not moved into the bin folders and NCrunch works fine.

You can refer to [Azure function:build issue](https://forum.ncrunch.net/yaf_postst2767_Azure-Function---build-issue.aspx)

If the above suggestions don't work then you can ask the same on [NCrunch forum](https://forum.ncrunch.net/) and also  open an issue on GitHub: [azure-functions-vs-build-sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues)

Comment: `ExcludeRestorePackageImports` does the job. Thanks!